# What Aquatic Mammal has no Tail?

Tags: zoology, species-identification

Found in a waterway in Butte County, CA. First thought it was a beaver kit, but it has no
tail.
What aquatic mammal has no tail?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is no tail? Muskrat?

Comment: Muskrats have a rat tail. This critter may have had a small knob of a tail, but the hair at the hindquarters was too wet to reveal much of anything.

Comment: Your individual might have had an accident in the past!

Comment: What size is it? I'd agree with kmm and Remi.b that it's a muskrat which lost its tail.

Comment: What a great picture!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a mountain beaver (*Aplodontia rufa*) to me. Location, appearance, and minimal tail all match.

---

**A bit more detail:**

Where I'm from on Washington's Olympic Peninsula, they're not uncommon, but Butte County is near the southern end of their distribution ([eol map page](http://eol.org/pages/34465/maps)) and they may be less common there, and limited to cooler higher elevations ([Beier 1989](https://oak.ucc.nau.edu/pb1/vitae/Beier.1989.Aplodontia.pdf)), and to wet habitats (their inability to concentrate urine (!) means they need to drink enormous quantities of water).

This white paper from USDA ([Arjo 2007](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/icwdm_usdanwrc/675)) is a great source, and more comprehensive than the  the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_beaver), which is also good.

---

Arjo, Wendy M. (2007). "Mountain Beaver: A Primitive Fossorial Rodent". USDA National Wildlife Research Center - Staff Publications. Paper 675.

Beir, Paul (1989). Journal of Wildlife Management 53(3) 649-654

Comment: Hey, Oreotrephes, thanks for taking the time to respond with the correct answer.
This is a video I shot of this animal, and it reveals that it definitely is the mountain beaver:
http://youtu.be/8Ljp1NiLvLU

Comment: Aw, what a cute little guy. Great footage!